# Print Without Margins in Omnigraffle

Tags: omnigraffle

I have an Omnigraffle canvas sized at the exact size of U.S. letter format (8.5 X 11 in). I want it to print out without any margins, but can't seem to find the correct settings to do so. I have set the canvas size and page setup properly, but the page always prints out with a small margin on all four sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set the margins to 0 under the document inspector?

[image: document inspector OmniGrafle]

**Edit:** never mind this step, you already had it set under Page Setup

> Also, make sure to select borderless by going to **Paper Handling > select *Scale to fit paper size* > *US Letter Borderless***
>
> [image: printer options pane]

Comment: Thank you! That resolved my problem by setting the margins in the document inspector.